# Pie timer with circle image not svg

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, timer

So on, I´m building a loading screen and have a hand drawn circle (just a png) and trying to find out how I can access that the circle just show over a specific time (set by js) the hole image like by a pie timer.

[image: The circle]

Sorry for my english and hope there is someone who can help!

Regards muuvmuuv

Comment: You can't do this easily with a PNG image.

Comment: You want it to countdown correct?

Comment: Yes right.. @user4875251

Comment: Have you tried masking? 

You can find a good tutorial here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: Yeah but I dont know how to mask a pie and style it after with jquery or smth @Engin